How to create the React app, and what is best way to do it?
I saw in official website and found that there is no
npx create-react-app appname!!
but instead I found:
npx create-expo-app
npx create-gatsby
npx create-remix
npx create-next-app@latest

Among these, it will be good to create the React app and
If support I used the next-app@latest, then how should I make it run.
for create-react-app, I used npm start after going into the app.
Also, now I need to see through next.js too?
Please help me to understand it.

Use Vite.
npm create vite@latest your-app-name -- --template react

Create React App is deprecated and no longer recommended.
